# How to create a ggplot when the answers are FALSE or TRUE?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-haven

How can I create a plot with ggplot when my answers are TRUE or FALSE?

This is my code:

```
t.obese<-master1%>%
  filter(Income>0,obese==TRUE)%>%
  select(Income,obese)

> head(t.obese)
  Income obese
1  21600    TRUE
2   4000    TRUE
3  12720    TRUE
4  26772    TRUE
```

when I am trying to create a plot , r tells me " Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type haven_labelled/vctrs_vctr/double. Defaulting to continuous.
Fehler: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic."

Thank you!

```
> dput(t.obese[1:10, ])
structure(list(Income = structure(c(1944, 4000, 16000, 19200, 
22800, 21600, 18000, 18000, 2000, 18000), label = "Wages,Salary from                    main job", format.stata = "%42.0g", labels = c(`[-5] in Fragebogenversion    nicht enthalten` = -5, 
 `[-2] trifft nicht zu` = -2), class = c("haven_labelled",      "vctrs_vctr", 
 "double")), obese = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: show your plot code?

Comment: What do you want to put on the x-axis? What do you want to put on the y-axis? What type of plot (bar, line, point...)? Do you want to use color or anything else?

Comment: As I am a very beginner I tried with

`p<-ggplot(t.obese, aes(x=obese, y=Income) +
  geom_bar()`

I would like to have a Boxplots, y= Income and x=obese

Comment: But  if it is a line, point or histogram any would be fine.. my main problem is the issue with the TRUE and FALSE

Comment: Do you want to show how the income differs across obese and not obese?

Comment: @LefkiosPaikousis yes!!

Comment: Could you share some data with `dput()`? With *"haven_labelled/vctrs_vctr/double"* being referenced, seems like there's a little more going on than just TRUE/FALSE values. Posting the results of `dput(t.obese[1:10, ])` would help a lot.

Comment: Though it may be as simple as a class conversion, you could try `ggplot(t.obese, aes(x=factor(obese), y=Income) +   geom_bar()`

Comment: @GregorThomas

`structure(list(Income = structure(c(1944, 4000, 16000, 19200, 
22800, 21600, 18000, 18000, 2000, 18000), label = "Wages,Salary from main job", format.stata = "%42.0g", labels = c(`[-5] in Fragebogenversion nicht enthalten` = -5, 
`[-2] trifft nicht zu` = -2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), obese = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
> `

Comment: @GregorThomas  i tried this but still its telling me the same error ... "ggplot(t.obese, aes(x=factor(obese), y=Income) +   geom_bar()"

Comment: Could you edit the `dput()` output into your question, in a code block? The comment formatting eats some of the important parts.

Comment: @GregorThomas i edited it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare Income distribution across obesity, then you need both obese = TRUE and obese = FALSE, so you can do the comparison

I randomly created an `non_obese` dataset just to do the comparison.
Also, I removed the `haven_labelled` class for the `Income` since it was causing some issues in the `reprex` rendering  [using `haven::zap_labels()`

Anyway, hope the following will help you get started

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(haven)

obese <- 
structure(list(Income = structure(c(1944, 4000, 16000, 19200, 
                                    22800, 21600, 18000, 18000, 2000, 18000), 
                                  label = "Wages,Salary from main job", 
                                  format.stata = "%42.0g", 
                                  labels = c(`[-5] in Fragebogenversion nicht enthalten` = -5,
                                             `[-2] trifft nicht zu` = -2), 
                                  class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr","double")), 
               obese = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)), 
          row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame"
          )


# remove the haven/labelled class of the income variable
obese <- 
  obese %>% 
  haven::zap_labels() 

non_obese <- 
  obese %>% 
  mutate(
    Income = Income - rnorm(1, mean = 1000, sd = 50),
    obese  = !obese
  )



full_data <- 
  bind_rows(obese, non_obese)


# Box plot 
full_data %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(obese, Income)
  )+
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5)+
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width  = 0.05))
```

[image]

```r
# Density plot
full_data %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(Income,fill = obese)
  )+
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

With the data you shared, which is minimal, tried this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code1
ggplot(as.data.frame(t.obese), aes(x=factor(obese), y=Income)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  xlab('Obese')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

Output:

[image]

And this:

```
#Code 2
ggplot(as.data.frame(t.obese), aes(x=factor(obese), y=Income)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_jitter()+
  geom_boxplot()+
  xlab('Obese')
```

Output:

[image]